# Accurev externally, git internally

Tags: git, version-control, accurev

I’m working on a project using Accurev as a VCS. Since I’m not at all familiar with it, I’m wondering if it would be a good idea to use git “internally” - meaning I would use git locally, then doing the “official” commits with Accurev.

Would this be an OK approach?

If yes, I would naturally want to exclude git from the Accurev versioning. Is it sufficient to have a .acignore that looks something like this:

```
myproject/.git
myproject/.git/*
myproject/.gitignore
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't know if it's an option for your organization, but AccuRev has a Git interface: http://www.accurev.com/products/gitcentric.

Comment: Not sure if it is of any use but you could consider using [ac2git](https://github.com/NavicoOS/ac2git) to continuously track the Accurev depot with the streams that you're working on and convert them to Git. This would allow you to work in Git and then simply apply the changes in Accurev once you feel they are ready. For the Git to Accurev part you could try using something like [legit-the-git](https://github.com/gmanley/legit-the-git) but I haven't tried it myself so I don't know if it works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use git and AccuRev side-by-side.  You mignt need to tune your .acignore, though.
From the AccuRev Help files:

> Examples
>
> A simple wild card pattern such as “*.doc” that is specified globally matches any of these names:
>
> docs/chap01.doc
>   docs/manuals/chap01.doc
>   docs/widgetproj/src/manuals/usergd/chap01.doc
>
> The pattern manuals/*.doc specified in docs/.acignore matches any of these names:
>
> docs/manuals/chap01.doc
>   docs/manuals/chap02.doc
>
> ... but not these names:
>
> docs/manuals/usergd/src/chap01.doc
>   docs/widgetproj/src/manuals/usergd/chap01.doc
>
> However, using ** to specify recursion as in manuals/*********/*.doc or manuals/**/*chap*.doc will match any occurrence of *.doc or *chap*.doc in any directory underneath the docs/manuals directory. See Wildcards in Ignore Patterns on page 12 for more information on using **.

Comment: Cool, I'll try to play with it a little. Thanks!

Comment: you also need to add '.accurev' to your .gitignore file. Might want '.git/**/*' to use accurev recursion wildcard.

Comment: I've got it working on several projects -- using both Git and AccuRev in the same local dir.  It takes a bit of tuning of the .acignore and .gitignore files, but it is doable.

Answer (score 5):

Options:

1) You might want to look into AccuRev's GitCentric interface. It will allow you to work in Git and have your content show up in AccuRev, or vice versa. This doesn't directly answer your question, but provides you a way to work in a tool you're familiar with.

2) If you're unfamiliar with AccuRev, they do sponsor monthly end user training sessions for free. You can sign up for the [Online Instructor-led Training](http://www.accurev.com/customer-support-resources/online-instructor-led-training). The AccuRev commands you'll need most often are: keep, promote, update and merge. Again not a direct answer, but learning is a life time goal or struggle depending on your prospective.

3) Using .acignore files to keep the Git files out of AccuRev would work. The .acignore files are designed to allow you to keep files not being managed by AccuRev, noted as "(external)", from being acted upon.

You said "I’m wondering if it would be a good idea to use git “internally” - meaning I would use git locally, then doing the “official” commits with Accurev." That's the joy and freedom of being a developer... you certainly can do that if you choose. You'll need to be careful as Git will not be the official source of record, but instead AccuRev has that role. You may find yourself having to do many merges if you don't keep your AccuRev workspace current via the update command.

If you do use GitCentric, then AccuRev will be the offical source of record at your site, but you'll be able to use Git for all of your work.

Please do respond with your path forward as I'm sure there are many curious developers out there who may want to know.

David

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears you need a Linux AccuRev server to use GitCentric.  Don't know what the OP's situation is w/r/t to Linux.

Answer (score 2):

AccuRev and Git can also be integrated using the GitCentric product. If you have AccuRev licenses already, GitCentric has a minor additional license cost. You can find out more at the following URL:

http://www.accurev.com/products/gitcentric

Answer (score 2):

You CAN work with both, but you probably shouldn't. They use quite different underlying models - ([Flexible vs static branching (Git vs Clearcase/Accurev)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763099/flexible-vs-static-branching-git-vs-clearcase-accurev)) & ([What is a one-sentence explanation of how Accurev works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620312/what-is-a-one-sentence-explanation-of-how-accurev-works)).

I have tried this (I've worked with just about every major SCM there is btw. Accurev and Clearcase are the worst, Git and SVN the best), and on large projects it quickly becomes more of a headache to deal with the double commit/merge/overlap than it does to just work with Accurev. This is because Accurev does "silent" updates to child streams/workspaces. What this means is that for large teams or frequently updated Accurev streams you often have to deal with the diffs in Git for each commit. Although this might sound like a positive thing, having to do this at least once per day for a number of files, some of which require merges is just not fun (or productive).

So, OK, you're thinking, what about this plugin? Well, to be frank, it's pretty awful in terms of it's implementation, and on top of an already somewhat clunky Accurev UI, it's just another barrier to good working practice and simplified SCM process.

This is surely too late for the person who originally asked the question, but for anyone else stumbling across this question, my advice would be (I know Accurev's so-called best feature, automatic updating of child by parent, is actually it's worst and most fundamental fault), to just take it on the chin and accept the pain of working with Accurev until such time as you can move to something more sensible like Git.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment, but it is possible to do it. If you tracked the stream with the [ac2git](https://github.com/orao/ac2git) script you could do rebasing in git and resolve your merges in the stream hoping for a long enough window to promote your whole changeset in one go.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it personally but [legit-the-git](https://github.com/gmanley/legit-the-git) is a Ruby project that is made to sync your local git with an Accurev system.

Comment: This is interesting, I'll have to give it a go!