# What is the difference between GIT and Accurev?

Tags: git, accurev

I need to know how does Accurev and GIT differ from each other in Source Code Management.
GIT being Distributed Version Control System but we can see that Accurev offers both the feature where we can have Client Server version control system and limit the number of files available in Developer's workspace but on the same time we can also let developer have the entire copy of the Source Repository

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a one-sentence explanation of how Accurev works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620312/what-is-a-one-sentence-explanation-of-how-accurev-works)

Comment: if you need to know the difference, you need to do some readings...

Answer (score 2):

My employer uses Accurev and we are migrating to git.

The two biggest differences between Accurev and git are:

1. Accurev's command line is more complex than git's.
2. With git you have a wide variety of command line shells and guis from which to choose,
   many of which are free.  With Accurev, there is only the Accurev
   gui
3. Accurev suffers performance issues when working in large repos.