# Synchronization in Clear Case

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am new to ClearCase UCM and want to understand something very basic

If I have a main branch, called Integration Stream. Also, there is a sub-branch of that, which is called development stream and if I create another development stream which is child of an existing development stream, will I be able to do synchronization (re-base and deliver) of this new development stream (sub-sub-branch) with the main branch/integration stream ?

Comment: One more query, is it possible to synchronize across two development streams that have the same integration stream as their parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will I be able to do synchronization (re-base and deliver) of this new development stream (sub-sub-branch) with the main branch/integration stream ?

You will be able to deliver from `subdev` stream to any other branch you want. `Integration` or even a stream from another project (with the same UCM components in it)

You will be able to rebase, however, only from the direct parent stream (`dev` stream here).

See also:

- "[ClearCase UCM hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9976424/6309)"
- "[UCM Clear Case: Hiereachy of streams in one project vs multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1589013/6309)"
- "[ClearCase: Is it possible to deliver or rebase selectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7939436/6309)"

> is it possible to synchronize across two development streams that have the same integration stream as their parent.

Yes, through deliver only: you can deliver to a destination stream which is at the same level as the source stream.
Actually, you can deliver to any stream (but if the destination stream is a *direct* child of the source stream, then a rebase is recommended).